# ##### appears instead of actual values in sql table

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i used

[column sal format A10;
set linesize 1500;]

to set width for the column sal and mgr. after that when i view the table the values in mgr and sal columns appears as ######.
now how to get the actual values??

Comment: I've tried to guess at some more specific tags based on the content of your question - if they're wrong, feel free to rollback

Comment: Why do you want a string-length format for a number column? Also what is your `numformat` set to, and how large are the numbers in those columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an invalid format model for a number column. The valid elements are [listed in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1299). SQL*Plus doesn't know what you mean, so it seems to be defaulting to the same behaviour it has if a number won't fit in a valid number format: "If a value cannot fit in the column, SQL*Plus displays pound signs (#) instead of the number."

You would only use the [charcater column formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1279) like `A10` if the result returned by the query was already a string, e.g. if you did `to_char(sal, '999G999G999') as sal`; but even then the maximum length is already set by the format model (to 12 in that case, to allow the +/- sign).

You probably don't need to format those columns at all, but if you are retrieving them as numbers and want to add formatting you need to use an appropriate model, e.g.

```
column salary format 999G999G999
```